# Angular 2: calculate price of dynamically generated <select> tags

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="filters">
    <label>Rooms?</label>
    <select class="full-width" (change)="create_accomodation($event.target.value)">
       <option [value]="1">01</option>
       <option [value]="2">02</option>
       <option [value]="3">03</option>
       <option [value]="4">04</option>
    </select>
<hr>

<div id="div_main"></div>
   <hr>
   <h1 class="pull-right">Price: ${{adultOption}}</h1>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

db = [
{
  "id": "1",
  "product_name": "6 Days at Karnataka",
  "states": ["Karnataka"],
  "cities": ["Bangalore"],
  "singlePrice":500,
  "twinPrice":800,
  "triplePrice":1100      
},
];

package: any;
filterData = [];
adultOption=0;
htmlCode;

ngOnInit() {
  this.packageList();
  this.create_accomodation(1);
}

packageList() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.db.length; i++) {
  this.filterData.push(this.db[i]);
  this.package = this.filterData;

  }
}
create_accomodation(num){
  var html = "";  
  for(var i=1; i<=num; i++)
  {
    html += '<div class="col-xs-4"><h4>Accomodation '+i+'</h4></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>No. of ADULTS</label><div class="selector"><select *ngFor="let d of db" (change)="calc_price($event.target.value)"><option value={{d.singlePrice}}>01</option><option value={{d.twinPrice}}>02</option><option value={{d.triplePrice}}>03</option></select></div></div>';  
  } 
  (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("div_main")).innerHTML= html;
  // this.htmlCode= html;
}

calc_price(price){
   var a=null;
   a=price;
   this.adultOption=a;
 }
}
```

In the above code when I select the number of rooms it dynamically generates the  tags (i.e accommodations) which are working fine. 
The dynamic  tags(i.e No. of Adults) that are generated Should have the following functionality:

1. Each accommodation should fetch the pricing details of each option(singlePrice, twinPrice, triplePrice) from an array "db".
2. calculate the price of each dynamic tag that is generated (Note: this will work when I directly put it in the html file and not working when I use "innerHTML").

Here is the link of code which I tried: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-calc-price?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Try `<div [innerHTML]="htmlCode"> </div>` in html and in the component, `this.htmlCode = html` ( uncomment this line)

Comment: @dileepkumar jami - I tried that one but it's not working. it prints the content inside the tag(like 010203).